# should I use tags or branches? Which is better for tracking your source code in Git of every nightly build with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I would like to know the experience of others and what would be the better strategy. I am supposing that branching is not that good, because of the space usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branching actually takes up the same amount of space as tagging (actually less space than a full tag). But the space used is besides the point; tags are indeed what you want to be using here, as they do not move, and thus are well suited for marking nightly builds.